# Was this a rapid SCHEDULED disassembly? How was it done?

Tags: safety, saturn-v, abort

The new Curious Droid video [Apollo's Forgotten Computer - The LVDC](https://youtu.be/p12CinjFh1I) discussed the Saturn V flight computer that's also discussed in answers to [Is this really the Saturn V computer only, or are there other systems here as well?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37140/12102).

At one point there is a discussion of the Launch Abort system and a few seconds of file footage is shown.

In addition to the launch abort rocket igniting, at about `11:18` the video shows a rapid disassembly<sup>†</sup> of several rocket components.

Was it intended for the rocket to "fall apart" like this into so many pieces? If so, how is this accomplished?

[image: rapid scheduled disassembly] GIF from [here](https://youtu.be/p12CinjFh1I)

<sup>†</sup>[Who coined the phrase 'Rapid Unscheduled Disassembly'?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/10022/12102)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**No.** I think this is actually the May 23, 1965 A-003 test, described in [my answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/29497/12102) to the question, *Could a spacecraft spin so fast that it spontaneously deconstructs?*

Notice that the rocket and Apollo CM are *spinning*. That isn't supposed to happen. In A-003, improperly installed gyros caused the vanes on the fins to deflect fully in one direction, imparting a spin that accelerated. Eventually this caused breakup of the Little Joe II rocket that triggered the actual abort.

Comment: I think you’re right! There’s are some images on https://www.drewexmachina.com/2016/01/20/the-first-launch-of-apollo-flight-hardware/ you could cite as evidence.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-003 also explains how the high roll rate affected the actual abort.